Robomaster Champion freezes after using plaintext protocol
The case is that I have connected the EP with RNDIS protocol by connecting to the correct IP, and it can successfully enter into the SDK mode.
However, as soon as it enters the SDK mode, the output stream from the Robomaster Champion freezes, but moving the mouse can move the gimbal but is unable to move chassis and see the updated video stream. Is there any workaround?
I have tried using both RNDIS and WiFi connection method and they all failed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
